# How to make an overall boxplot alongside factors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot that shows all of the factors of a variable, along with sample size, and at eh end of the plot also want an overall boxplot that combines all of the values into one. I am using the following line of code to do everything except making the overall plot:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(plyr)
xlabels <- ddply(extract8, .(Fuel), summarize, xlabels = paste(unique(Fuel), '\n(n = ', length(Fuel),')'))

ggplot(extract8, aes(x = Fuel, y = Exfiltration.Fraction.Percentage))+geom_boxplot()+
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill="pink") + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels[['xlabels']]) + ggtitle("Exfiltration Fraction (%) by Fuel   Type")
```

Not sure on how to proceed regarding adding a boxplot that combines all of the factors into one.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the most elegant way to solve it, but it works:

1. Copy your dataset into a new object.
2. Within the new object, replace the content of the variable containing the factors with the label you would like, for instance, "Total".
3. Use `rbind` to attach the old and new objects together and attribute the result to the new object.
4. In `ggplot` replace the old object by the new object.

I had the same issue, couldn't find an answer and proceeded this way.