# How to ggplot all id's on x axis plus another with a total of all id's

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

I have the above graph and I would simply like to add one more x axis id that is a total of all the other id's; i.e. an "all cars" boxplot representing the total variation of all the different types of cars combined.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900975/dotplot-with-boxplot-group-summaries (this is basically what you want without the faceting -- you'll need a second data.frame)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190627/how-to-make-an-overall-boxplot-alongside-factors-in-r